# Azure AD SAML SSO - Signout process

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2b

I didn't quite understand the logout process in AD. 
Say a user logs out from other app (not mine) that's connected to AD, would my SP get called when it happens?
Another thing that i'm missing is, what happens when user was removed/deactivated from their directory? how would I know when to clear their session? couldn't find anything regarding this issue in AD's docs.

Answer (score 0):

The following diagram shows the workflow of the [Azure AD single sign-out process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol).

[image]

If the user logs out from one app connected to AD(the same tenant as yours), he will be signed out from other apps connected to the same AD.

If a user was removed from their directory, the user will get an authentication issue.

[image]

Comment: This is clear to me. But, my SP should know about such events so I can clear user's session on my system (SP). Or do I have to check on each request to the SP if the user is logged in to AD

Comment: And if I have to check on request if the user is logged in/exists in the AD, how do I do it? is there any endpoint for that purpose ?